# Navbar fits on most pages except one

Tags: html, css

The navbar on my homepage is cropping out my last link while on my other pages it works perfectly fine.

Excuse the extraneous code for all of this, this is all new to me.

```css
html {
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
}
/* HTML code */

header {
 font-size:3.5em;
}

h1 {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 250%;
}
/*H1 style */

h2 {
 font-size: 130%;
}
/*H2 style */

table {
 border: 3px solid white;
 text-align: center;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
/* tale style */

th {
 text-align: center;
 font-size:120%;
 border: 3px solid white;
 border-collapse:collapse;
}
/* Table Header style */

td {
 text-align: Left;
 border-left: 3px solid white;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
/*table cell alignment */

p {
 font-size: 100%;
}
/*paragraph style */

.body {
 font:helvetica, serif;
 color: white;
 overflow:auto;
 background-color: black;
 font-family: Arial, Verdana;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
 margin:auto;
 text-align: center;
 position:fixed;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
/* Body style */

.topnav {
 background-color: black;
 overflow:hidden;
 position:fixed;
 height: 120px;
 width: 100%;
}
/* Navbar style */

.topnav a {
 font:serif;
 float:left;
 color:white;
 text-align:center;
 padding: 12px 14px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 24px;
 height: 120px;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 line-height: 90px;
 width: 14.59%;
}
/* Navbar component style */

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
/* Hover Navbar option */

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
/* Active Navbar option */

.BG1 {
  background-image: url('CNRTap2.jpg');
  height: 80%; 
  width:100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
/* Background 1 */

.BG2 {
  background-image: url('CNRPizza1.jpg');
  height: 80%; 
  width:100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
/* Background 2 */

.BG3 {
  background-image: url('CNRPing1.jpg');
  height: 80%; 
  width:100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
/* Background 3 */

.logo {
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 16.666%px;
 height: 90px;
 padding-top: 15px;
 margin-right:20px;
 margin-left:20px;
 float: left;
}
/* Logo in Navbar */

.footer {
 text-align: center;
 background-color: grey;
 padding: 15px;
}
/* Footer */
/* Add social media links and logo */

.form {
 text-align:center;
 position:center;
 padding-left:10px;
}
/* Contact Us Form */

input[type=text], input[type=email], [type=number],  select, textarea {
 width: 40%;
 border: 2px solid white;
 border-radius:3px;
 padding:15px;
 margin:10px;
}/*-- Form input styles */

input[type=submit] {
 background-color:black;
 color:white;
 font-size: 20px;
 padding:15px 15px;
 border:1px white;
 border-radius:3px;
 cursor:pointer;
 border:2px solid white
}
/* Submit button style */

input[type=submit]:hover {
 background-color:white;
 color:black;
}
/*Submit button hover style */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title> Standard Cocktail Bar Home Page </title>
<meta name="author" content="joshualavulohodges@gmail.com">
<meta name="description" content="This page is homepage of Standard Cocktail Bar">
<meta name="keywords" content="Alcohol, Gungahlin, Drinks, Food, Standard Bar, Cocktail">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=auto,  initial-scale=1">
<link href="Stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- Meta Data -->
</head>

<body>
 <div class="body">
  <nav>
   <div class="topnav">
    <img class="logo" src="logo1.png">
    <a class="active" href="Home Page.html">Home </a>
    <a href="AboutUs.html">About Us </a>
    <a href="WhatsOn.html">Whats On </a>
    <a href="Menu.html">Menu </a>
    <a href="ContactUs.html">Contact Us </a>
   </div>
  </nav>
<!--NavBar-->

 <div class="BG1"></div>
<!--BG1-->

 <h1> Set Title</h1>
<!--Heading-->

 <p> Intro to business </p>
 <p> Quick Info of business </p>
<!--Business Info-->

 <div class="BG2"></div>
<!--BG2-->


 <table style="width:80%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto">
  <caption style="font-size:180%"> <b>Opening Hours</b></caption>
  <tr>
    <th> Days </th><th>Hours</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Monday</td><td>Closed</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tuesday</td><td>12:00pm - 9:00pm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Wednesday</td><td>12:00pm - Late</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Thursday</td><td>12:00pm - Late</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Friday</td><td>12:00pm - Late</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Saturday</td><td>10:00pm - Late</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sunday</td><td>12:00pm - Late</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
<!--Opening Hours-->
 
 <p> Summary of promos </p>
<!--Promo Info-->

 <div class="BG3"></div>
<!--BG3-->

 <footer>
  <p> insert some social media links etc </p>
 </footer>
<!--Footer-->

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a note for you since you're new to this community: try to share only the relevant parts of your code. That'll make others to better understand your question and answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `overflow: hidden;` from your`.topnav` class. Style `overflow: hidden;` hides the all elements, which exists deyond the screen view port.

```
.topnav {
    background-color: black;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    position: fixed;
    height: 120px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it just stacks to underneath, how would i keep it on the one line? the navbar also resizes to a smaller size on the other pages

Comment: @SLHEFC1928 Please go through this link .https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/04r1mezb/13/   . Is this you are looking for?